# Wrap a created text node with an element WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm editing a script that at one point does the following:

`err_node = document.createTextNode(err_decoded_str);`

However I need the resulting text node to be wrapped in `<label class="error">generated error node in here</label>`

How can this be done without using jQuery? If needs be I can change `createTextNode()` to a different function to achieve this.

Comment: is the label already in the document or do you have to create it? And where it should be appended?

Comment: Poor souls that have to write 4 lines of code instead of `$('<label>', { 'class': 'error', text: err_decoded_str })` - I believe you will use an abstraction layer for this, just make sure to not reinvent the wheel more than what it is worth.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Do not forget the KB's of JavaScript you include for that one line. ;)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Depending on your organization, it can be incredibly difficult to get them to use any library, even one as ubiquitous as jQuery.  Sometimes raw JavaScript is an absolute necessity.

Comment: @epascarello True that. `=]` My projects usually do heavy DOM manip so I start right off with jQuery to don't start reinventing the wheel. Travis, you're right, thankfully most organizations I worked with had a jQuery requirement instead of a no-jQuery one. `;)` Didn't want to start a discussion, done with the off-topic talk. `:P`

Comment: I would much rather have used jQuery, I actually know what I'm doing with that. I've "grown up" using it and really struggle with DOM manip without it on the odd occasion I'm forced not to use it. Probably not a very good thing that I can't be without it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So change it to use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) instead

```
err_node = document.createTextNode(err_decoded_str);
```

to

```
err_node = document.createElement("label");
err_node.className = "error";
err_node.innerHTML = err_decoded_str;
```

If you want, you can create a textnode and append it to the err_node.

```
err_node = document.createElement("label");
err_node.className = "error";
var err_textnode = document.createTextNode(err_decoded_str);
err_node.appendChild(err_textnode);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap the text in a `<label>` it becomes an element instead of a text node.  Look at `document.createElement` in [the MDN documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

Answer (score 0):

```
label = document.createElement('label');
label.className = 'error';
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err_decoded_str));
// attach the label to where ever its supposed to go
```

Answer (score 0):

```
err_node = document.createTextNode(err_decoded_str);
var label = document.createElement("label"); // create label element
label.classList.add("error"); // add error class to label
label.appendChild(err_node); // append err_node to label
console.log(label);
```